# facebook api - fql - exact difference between modified and modified_major

Tags: iphone, facebook-fql

I have found the Facebook API's very limited. [Here is what I'm looking at](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/album). It is so vague it is ridiculous. Maybe they want to keep it that way so they can change it at any time?

Anyywayy, I'm wondering specifically whether comment additions to albums or album photos are included in modified or modified_major. Is modified_major JUST additions/deletions of photos? Does that include changing a photo's description?

Thanks so much!

Answer (score 0):

I haven't worked with this particular table but, have you tried changing a photo's description and then querying the table to see if it updates to that time?